# Extension of $\sigma$-additive vector measures on a ring and the relationship between the corresponding total variation functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $\Omega$ be a set
- $\mathcal S\subseteq2^\Omega$ be a set with $\emptyset\in\mathcal S$
- $\mathcal S_{\text{loc}}:=\left\{A\subseteq\Omega:A\cap S\in\mathcal S\text{ for all }S\in\mathcal S\right\}$
- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $\mu:\mathcal S\to E$ with $\mu(\emptyset)=0$

Now, let $$\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}(A):=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu(R_i)\right\|_E:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }R_1,\ldots,R_k\in\mathcal S\text{ are pairwise disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kR_i\subseteq A\right\}$$ for $A\subseteq\Omega$.

It's easy to see that $\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}$ is monotone. Moreover, if $I$ is a set and $(A_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq2^\Omega$ is disjoint, then $$\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}\left(\biguplus_{i\in I}A_i\right)\ge\sum_{i\in I}\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}(A_i)\;.\tag1$$ If $(A_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathcal S_{\text{loc}}$ and $(\mu(S_i))_{i\in I}$ is summable with $$\sum_{i\in I}\mu(S_i)=\mu\left(\biguplus_{i\in I}S_i\right)\tag2$$ for all disjoint $(S_i)_{i\in I}$ with $\biguplus_{i\in I}S_i\in\mathcal S$, then we even got equality in $(1)$.

So, we immediately obtain that if $\mu$ is ($\sigma$-)additive, then $\left.\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}\right|_{\mathcal S_{\text{loc}}}$ is ($\sigma$-)additive. And clearly, if $\mathcal S$ is $\cap$-stable, then $\mathcal S_{\text{loc}}=\mathcal S$.

> Let $\mathcal A:=\sigma(\mathcal S)$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal S$. Suppose $\mu$ has an extension to a $\sigma$-additive $\nu:\mathcal A\to E$. What is the relation between $\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}$ and $\operatorname{Var}_\nu^{\mathcal A}$?
>
> My hope is that $\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}$ and $\operatorname{Var}_\nu^{\mathcal A}$ at least coincide on $\mathcal S$.

If necessary, you can assume that $\mathcal S$ is a ring or even an algebra on $\Omega$.

I've got a pretty hard time to figure out under which conditions on the objects we are able to prove the existence of a unique extension $\nu$ as described above.

I've consulted Theorem 7.4 of *Vector Integration and Stochastic Integration in Banach Spaces* by Dinculeanu and Theorem 5.2 of *Vector Measures* by Diestel and Uhl.

My problem with Dinculeanu is his notation for the total variation of a measure, since that notation doesn't make clear from which system ($\mathcal S$ or $\mathcal A$) the constituents of the partitions in the supremum are taken.

> So, I'm interested in a further reference for the extension of $\mu$. The case I'm most interested in is $\mathcal S$ being a ring, $E$ being complete and $\mu$ being $\sigma$-additive (on $\mathcal S$) with $\operatorname{Var}_\mu^{\mathcal S}(\Omega)<\infty$.